# How to insert multiple records in laravel (with for)

Tags: php, laravel

Im using laravel Seeder DB to insert multiple records with just one query, but I always get the same error:

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

I create an array and push another to them like this:

```
 for ($ciclo=0, $diasCorridos =0 ; $ciclo < $totalUnidades; $ciclo++, $diasCorridos++, $corredorAbcdario++) { 

        //concatenado
        $codigoUnidad = $codigoSubsector."-".$codigoSector."-".($ciclo+1);//."-".$codigoSubsector."-".$ciclo+1;




        if (($diasCorridos) == $cantidadUnidades) { 

            if($ciclo == $diasEntreInicio){
            $Numero_Unidad++;
        }
            //Se reinicia para poder saber cuando puedo iniciar otra unidad
            $diasCorridos = 0;
            $diaInicio=$diaInicio+$diasEntreInicio;
            $corredorAbcdario=0;

        }



        $subfrente= $codigoFuente."-".$abcdario{$corredorAbcdario};

        //
        $mostrar = "Codigo unidad : ".$codigoUnidad." diaInicio : ".$diaInicio." subfrente por unidad: ".$subfrente." Numero unidad: ".$Numero_Unidad." prg tipo un".$claseunidad."tipo ".$idPrg_Config_Subsector;

        //
        $mostrar2 = $mostrar2.$mostrar."--";

       //$arrayAuxiliar = array("".$tipounidad,"".$claseunidad,"".$idPrg_Obra,"".$idPrg_Config_Subsector,"".$ciclo+1,"".$Numero_Unidad,"".$codigoUnidad,"".$diaInicio,"","",);

         $arrayAuxiliar = array( 'idPrg_Tipo_Unidad' => ''.$tipounidad,
                            'idPrg_Clase_Unidad' =>  ''.$claseunidad,
                            'idPrg_Obra' =>  ''.$idPrg_Obra,
                            'idPrg_Config_Subsector' => ''.$idPrg_Config_Subsector, 
                            'Secuencia_Unidad' => ''.$ciclo+1, 
                            'Numero_Unidad' => ''.$Numero_Unidad, 
                            'Codigo_Unidad' => ''.$codigoUnidad,
                            'Dia_Inicio' => ''.$diaInicio, 
                            'Subfrente_Unidad' => ''.$subfrente, 
                            'created_at' => '',
                            'updated_at' => ''
                             );

        array_push($arrayFinal,$arrayAuxiliar);
      }....
```

And im trying this:

```
 DB::table('prg_unidad')->insertGetId($arrayFinal, 1);
```

¿Any idea?

Comment: I can't say this is a duplicate because the other question is open, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445607/database-seeding-insert-multiple-records-in-one-query  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339520/laravel-4-database-insert-error-preg-replace-parameter-mismatch-pattern-is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Seeder - multiple rows in DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589426/laravel-5-seeder-multiple-rows-in-db)

Comment: no bros, not duplicate; im creating the array with a loop, not writing like that posts.

Comment: I would recommend you to write variable names and code in english language. In case you ask for help like in this case, understanding what is being done is important and naming variables in english helps a lot in that.